# How can I force a socket to be blocked on send

Tags: networking

I am chasing down a bug in my code that I think might have to do with a socket blocking on send.  I'm working in C#, using the Socket class in blocking mode.  I would love to be able to do some testing in my local environment to see what happens if the SendTo method blocks on send, but I am not sure if there is a way to do this on Windows.

What I am trying to do right now is to have two programs which I'm running locally.  One sets up a UDP socket and then reads data very slowly (1 second delay between reads).  The other program just sends a firehose of data to the first--one 63k datagram after another as fast as possible in an infinite loop.  I was hoping that eventually some buffer somewhere would fill up and SendTo would block, but I am not having any luck.

Is my test fundamentally flawed, or is there some way to actually do this in Windows?

One other note: I am sending my packets on 127.0.0.1--do I actually need to have the packets routed out of my NIC for this to have any chance of working?

Comment: I don't think you use "block" in the usual way. Typically, when we say a socket blocks on sending, we mean that it blocks until the OS sends the data to the **local** network card.  It doesn't wait at all for the receiver.

Comment: @MSalters My knowledge of networking is definitely a little shaky--usually things just seem to work!  If that's the case, I'm having a hard time understanding why send would ever block, or how I could simulate it.  I'm sure there are a bunch of factors that I'm not considering.  Is there any way to test this scenario or should I just give up?  I'm getting the sense that nobody has actually ever tried this before...

Comment: Well, in the good old days of the Internet, it was quite easy to hit the 9600 baud limits of your dial-up modem. That could block quite fast, especially since your PC likely did not have that much RAM to buffer things locally either.  But a modern PC sending data to localhost? That's just telling the CPU "that memory block now belongs to the other process", basically.

Comment: XY problem. You should ask about your actual bug, rather than how to reproduce what you *think* the cause might be.

Comment: @user207421 Indeed the actual bug was not related to SendTo--this was actually process of elimination.  There were only two possible causes that I could see--SendTo blocking, or a deadlock.  Naturally, it did turn out to be the deadlock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UDP is a datagram protocol for unreliable delivery. Your OS can just discard packets; there's no expectation of buffering. In fact, for applications like video streaming it's GOOD to discard packets, else you can end up with a lot of lag. UDP applications should detect lost packets themselves and adapt, e.g. by lowering the video resolution (or whatever makes sense for your type of application).

TCP is the reliable protocol. The OS will talk with the other OS to verify that all TCP data arrived. A slow reader also acknowledges the data slowly, which in turn slows down the sender. `localhost` simplifies this a bit, but for applications that doesn't really matter.

**[edit]**
Addressing your problem a bit more directly: since UDP doesn't care one iota about receiving data, you can just drop that receiver. That will loose 100% of the packets, but you were only wondering about the send part.

As for the buffering, you're right that `localhost` won't be effective. It's way too fast. The best approach might be to intentionally worsen your network connection. Perhaps your Ethernet can be forced to 100 Mbps? Perhaps an USB2 network adapter? UDP might be tolerant about losses, but if you run UDP over a VPN over TCP you suddenly get a bunch of slower software layers. Packets can now get lost *after* the VPN server, but any packets lost on the way to the VPN server need to be resent. And when that VPN connection runs over some bad WiFi, there's bound to be some packet loss.

Comment: Maybe I'm going down a rabbit hole with this whole thing.  I don't actually care about dropped packets--in fact, I hadn't event considered that SendTo would block for any appreciable period of time precisely because I am using UDP--I just figured that some packets might get dropped, and so be it--the app has logic to handle that.

But yet I read the "Remarks" section here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.sendto?view=net-6.0

"If you are using a connectionless protocol in blocking mode, SendTo will block until the datagram is sent."

Comment: @erikjw: Note that you're looking at C# documentation. " successful completion of the `SendTo` method means that the underlying system has had room to buffer your data" talks about the C# method, but the underlying system is Windows.